# Python: csv to json converter value to key pair

Tags: python, json, csv, python-3.x

I had a Python beginners course last year. Now I am trying to get a csv to json converter. I have searched quite some time and adapted and changed some of the code I found, until the output looked similar to what I want. I am using Python 3.4.2.

@kvorobiev this is an excerpt of my CSV, but it will do for the case. The first time Converting will work. After the second time you will see that the order of the headings will change within the json file.

The csv file looks like this

```
Document;Item;Category
4;10;C
```

What I am getting in the output file as of now (after applying the changes from kvorobiev):

```
[
{
    "Item": "10",
    "Category": "C",
    "Document": "4"
};
]
```

The json string I want to get in the output file should look like:

```
[
{
   "Document": "4",
   "Item": "10",
   "Category": "C"
},
]
```

You will notice the headings are in the wrong order.

Here is the code:

```
import json
import csv

csvfile = open('file1.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file1.csv'.replace('.csv','.json'), 'w')

jsonfile.write('[' + '\n' + ' ')
fieldnames = csvfile.readline().replace('\n','').split(';')
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('file.csv')) -1

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
i = 0
for row in reader:  
  i += 1
  json.dump(row, jsonfile, indent=4,sort_keys=False)
  if i < num_lines:
    jsonfile.write(',')
  jsonfile.write('\n')
jsonfile.write(' ' + ']')

print('Done')
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: you output json is valid ? Can you check on http://jsonlint.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I don't know if the json output is valid, but it is what I need to further process the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace line

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
```

with

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames, delimiter=';')
```

Also, you open `file1.csv` and later get lines number from `file.csv`

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('file.csv')) -2
```

Your solution could be reduced to

```
import json
import csv
csvfile = open('file1.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file1.csv'.replace('.csv','.json'), 'w')
jsonfile.write('{\n[\n')
fieldnames = csvfile.readline().replace('\n','').split(';')
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames, delimiter=';')
for row in reader:  
  json.dump(row, jsonfile, indent=4)
  jsonfile.write(';\n')
jsonfile.write(']\n}')
```

If you want to save order of columns from csv you could use

```
from collections import OrderedDict
...
for row in reader:  
  json.dump(OrderedDict([(f, row[f]) for f in fieldnames]), jsonfile, indent=4)
  jsonfile.write(';\n')
jsonfile.write(']\n}')
```

Comment: Thank you, you are great! Completely solved my problem.

Comment: @user87290 Could you provide your input file?

Comment: EDIT The headings still get mixed up. but I fixed the dump. Input file is 17,4MB big...

Comment: I have added some explanation to my original question. Hopefully it is understandable ;)

Comment: I have tried sort_key=True, which put all the keys in alphabetical order. False just did nothing. The correct order should be:
Document
Item
Category
What I get is something other:
Item
Document
Category
OR
Category
Document
Item
It works as excpectet very seldomly.

Comment: When I use csv.reader istead of csv.dictreader the values are in the correct order, but the keys are missing.